# Is there any way we can create angular library project without actually creating "project" folder using angular CLI?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an angular library project using -

ng new my-library-wp --create-application=false

cd my-library-wp

ng generate library test-library

It is generating library test-library inside project folder.
I want to create library test-library without project folder and without manual configuration.

Tried -
ng new my-library-wp --create-application=false
cd my-library-wp
ng generate library test-library

Comment: The Angular CLI ng generate library command always creates a library inside the projects folder. It is a part of Angular's design philosophy for handling workspace and library setup.

However, if you really want to create the library at the root level without manually moving files around, you could consider creating a workspace without an initial application (as you've done), and then manually re-arrange the generated library files and modify the angular.json file accordingly.

But, doing this would go against Angular's workspace philosophy and might have unforeseen implications.